# Edit header/body HTML code in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I am not familiar with with the Mediawiki script and having a hard time finding stuff. I need to make some pretty big changes to the header and body tags but I haven't figured out where and which file holds those two tags.

Does someone know the location and name of the files where I can edit the header and body content?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_1

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Vector skin (which is default) you can change the header and body within the file `mediawiki/skins/Vector/VectorTemplate.php`.

Be aware that this file is overwritten if you update MediaWiki.